# Is there a way to store SPARQL queries as instances in an RDF file?

Tags: sparql, rdf, owl, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am creating a database which encodes directed acyclic graphs (DAGs), where nodes are RDF instances and edges are object properties.  Ultimately, I would like to create SPARQL queries which match graph patterns in my set of DAGs.  There are many (~200) subtree patterns that I am interested in and would like to somehow store these queries to execute later.

The SPARQL below is a toy example of selecting instances of DAGs having a set of nodes and connections:

```
SELECT ?dag
WHERE {
?dag :has_node ?n1 ;
     :has_node ?n2 ;
     :has_node ?n3 .
?n1 rdfs:type :Type1 ;
    :parent_of ?n2 .
?n2 rdfs:type :Type2 ;
    :parent_of ?n3 .
?n3 rdfs:type :Type3 .

}
```

Is it possible to store SPARQL queries like the one above as instances in RDF?  If so, can I refer to the instance in a SPARQL query and have it translated into SPARQL?  (See below)

```
SELECT ?dag
WHERE {
?dag :has_graph_pattern ?graphPattern .
}
```

The `?graphPattern` variable would be an instance that would encode the same thing as the first SPARQL query.

Thanks for any feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested in [@Roos' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69904955/3025856), I was able to encode my subgraphs in SHACL rules and use them to create triples relating DAGs and subgraphs.

In the example below, there are two DAGs—`DAG1` and `DAG2`—whose nodes can have three possible node labels: `A`, `B`, or `C`. For this example, I want to find DAGs with the `C<--B-->C` pattern, and then create a new triple linking that DAG with an instance representing this subgraph:

```
ex:DAG ex:has_subgraph ex:subGraph1
```

This pattern I'm matching is highlighted in yellow in the image below:

[image: DAGs in toy Dataset]

The subgraph pattern can be encoded into a SHACL rule shown below in TTL. Be sure to have `sh:declare` statements preceding rules, as this may cause issues with the SHACL rule inferencer you use. This is stored in a file called `dagShapes.ttl`:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#> .

ex:
        sh:declare [
                sh:prefix "ex" ;
                sh:namespace "http://example.com/ns#"^^xsd:anyURI ;
        ] .

ex:DAGSubGraphRule1
        a sh:NodeShape ;
        sh:targetClass ex:DAG ;
        sh:rule [
                a sh:SPARQLRule ;
                sh:prefixes ex: ;
                sh:construct """ 
                        CONSTRUCT {
                                $this ex:has_subgraph ex:subGraph1 .
                        }
                        WHERE {
                                $this ex:has_node ?n1 ;
                                      ex:has_node ?n2 ;
                                      ex:has_node ?n3 .

                                ?n1 a ex:nodeType_B ;
                                        ex:parent_of ?n2 ;
                                        ex:parent_of ?n3 .
                                ?n2 a ex:nodeType_C .
                                ?n3 a ex:nodeType_C .

                        }
                        """ ;
        ] ;
.
```

The DAGs in this example are encoded in their own file called `dagData.ttl` like this:

```
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sh: <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix ex: <http://example.com/ns#> .

ex:DAG1
        a ex:DAG ;
        ex:has_node ex:d1_n1 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d1_n2 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d1_n3 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d1_n4 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d1_n5 .

ex:d1_n1 a ex:nodeType_A ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n2 .
ex:d1_n2 a ex:nodeType_A ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n3 .
ex:d1_n3 a ex:nodeType_B ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n4 ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n5 .
ex:d1_n4 a ex:nodeType_C .
ex:d1_n5 a ex:nodeType_C .

ex:DAG2
        a ex:DAG ;
        ex:has_node ex:d2_n1 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d2_n2 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d2_n2 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d2_n2 ;
        ex:has_node ex:d2_n2 .

ex:d1_n1 a ex:nodeType_A ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n2 .
ex:d1_n2 a ex:nodeType_A ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n3 .
ex:d1_n3 a ex:nodeType_B ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n4 .
ex:d1_n4 a ex:nodeType_C ;
        ex:parent_of ex:d1_n5 .
ex:d1_n5 a ex:nodeType_C .
```

The DAG file and the subgraph shapes file are then passed to a [SHACL rule inference tool](https://github.com/TopQuadrant/shacl). The inferencer is run like this in the command line:

```
shaclinfer -datafile dagData.ttl -shapesfile dagShapes.ttl
```

The output from the inferencer shows that `DAG1` was correctly associated with my subgraph pattern!

```
@prefix dash:    <http://datashapes.org/dash#> .
@prefix ex:      <http://example.com/ns#> .
@prefix graphql: <http://datashapes.org/graphql#> .
@prefix owl:     <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix rdf:     <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs:    <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix sh:      <http://www.w3.org/ns/shacl#> .
@prefix swa:     <http://topbraid.org/swa#> .
@prefix tosh:    <http://topbraid.org/tosh#> .
@prefix xsd:     <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

ex:DAG1  ex:has_subgraph  ex:subGraph1 .
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to go would be using the [SHACL Advanced Features](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-af/) vocabulary. You could store your `?dag` variable as the `?this` variable in a shape graph (see the section about [SPARQL-Based Targets](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl-af/#SPARQLTarget)). You can then store the pattern after a `sh:select` predicate and use the select query as your pattern for finding your `dag`.

Comment: Thank you Roos for this catalyst!  This could also be a viable option for me as well.  I'll try implementing something simple and get back to you!

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to encode a SPARQL query as OWL-but I'm not sure of anyone that's done it (it would be an involved process). As for pulling it out, definitely. It will be retrieved as a [SPARQL Query Result](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-results-json/), which you'd have to manually parse to get the full sparql query out.

In short, it's possible to embed a sparql query in an OWL document by first transforming the query to RDF. You can certainly pull the query out, _but processing to reconstruct the original query has to be done in another system (Java, Python, etc). Sounds like a cool topic for a paper, but *lots* of work around serializing and retrieving the query. Do I recommend it? Not if you're trying to do anything immediate.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback @Thomas! Storing these subgraphs is just the beginning, as I am trying to use them to add more triples to my database.  DAGs will be connected based on shared subgraph patterns.  Maybe I should make code that dynamically creates `CONSTRUCT` statements that will run upon generating the database rather figure out how to store queries and then run them?  Writing logic outside of SPARQL is also on the table as well.